# Formula for minimum distance for circles what won't touch each other depending on n?

Tags: geometry, angle

Let's say that I have a circle, which is the "middle circle" (red in the pictures below). I also have a number (n) of identical circles, that should appear around the middle one, without touching. For the first few Ns, they can basically hug the middle circle (without touching), and they will fit. At some point, there will be too many, so they will have to be further and further away from the middle circle, to maintain that round formation without touching each other.

I am wondering if there is a formula, that given n the number of outer circles, d the starting angle (there will always be a circle at this angle if n > 0), and k the (constant) minimum distance between two circles (always >= 0, so that they won't touch), and i the circle number, I could get its exact location (assuming the middle circle is at (0, 0)), or just its distance from the middle circle?

A picture is worth a thousand words, so here is what the first few Ns would look like.

Please forgive the horrible paint drawings.

[image: A few of the first Ns]

So what formula could I use in that situation?

Comment: for two I don't think minimum exists it must be infimum or something like that i think the problem continues for larger number of circles (you can always get the circles slightly closer and so on..)

Comment: Do all the circles have to go in one layer? You can essentially pretend the circles are touching and keep them a distance $\varepsilon > 0$ apart (this will propogate a term through to the final result, but it will be negligible), so it makes sense to just deal with the problem where the circles are tangent.

Comment: I think you want to ask this question: Find the smallest (infimum) radius  $r$ such that the ball of radius $r$ such that it will contain $n$ balls of a given radius.

Comment: @yanko that's probably a better wording than what I wrote. I'm not a mathematician, so I wasn't sure how to describe this problem correctly. Feel free to suggest an edit.

Comment: To clarify things: 1) Should the $n$ black circles be at the same distance from the red one? 2) Has every circle (red and black) the same radii? 3) Would you admit that the circles were tangent? (If not, I'm almost sure that the problem has no solution) 4) From your drawings, it seems that the centers of the black circles are the vertices of a regular polygon. Do you know about complex numbers and/or trigonometry? They can be *very* handy for this problem.

Comment: @ajotatxe Every single circle is identical as for size, shape, etc. The color only differs in the exemple to make understanding easier. Every single black circle should be at the exact same distance from the red one, and the space between 2 black circles should always be the same except when n is too low for them to make a complete bigger circle around the red. I am not sure wha tangent would mean in this context, I apologise. Yes, you could see the center of black circles as vertices of a regular polygon, if that's any help to figure out the solution.

Comment: @ajotatxe I have very limited mathematical knowledge (studying computer programming). I have completed high school, college and all required math classes in university, but never went any further than what is necessary for my major, so no I have no knowledge or experience with complex numbers. I remember a bit of trigonometry from high school, but  it was probably not advanced enough to be relevant here?

Comment: Complex numbers are optional, but trigonometry is a must to solve this problem.

Comment: Hint: for $n \ge 3$ the centers of the black circles are the vertices of a [regular polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_polygon) with $n$ sides. For $n \gt 6$ the side length of the regular polygon is $2r+k$ where $r$ is the common radius of the circles. From there, you can determine the distance from the center of the red circle to the center of any black circle and, once you have that, the rest is just working out some straightforward calculations.

Comment: Maybe you could have a look at some works about the Kissing Number Problem. What you describe here is the case $n=2$, but maybe you can get some información from there